# How can I compare two SQLlite dataset in Python and search for similarities?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, dataset, compare

So basically, I have two databases. One for "student" and one for "teacher". The teacher database is already saved on the server and the students database will be created by user input.

this is for the teacher (also saved separately in a teacher.db file)

```
c.execute(“””CREATE TABLE teacher( 
ID varchar,
name text
age integer
interest1 varchar
interest2 varchar
)”””) 
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

example: `c.execute(“INSERT INTO student VALUES (‘Lisa’, ‘35’, ‘spanish’, ‘productivity’)`

This is the table for the students and the data will be saved in a separate file called student.db

```
c.execute(“””CREATE TABLE student( 
ID varchar,
name text
age integer
interest1 varchar
interest2 varchar
)”””) 
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

And an example of a person looks like this:

```
c.execute(“INSERT INTO student VALUES (‘Max’, ‘23’, ‘spanish’, ‘programming’)”
```

Now, I want to compare the user input, which created the second database. We can see that the value "spanish" is used by both parties. Now I want to create an algorithm that is like this: if the keyword used from the student is equal to one of the datasets in the database of the teachers, I want to print out their name.

I tried to work with if then but nothing really worked.

It's my second day in learning python please be nice even if this all sounds pretty dumb.

Comment: Hello @Sara did you try any coding for this?

Comment: Do you want to print the name of the student or the teacher? or both like Spanish Lisa Max?

Comment: so you want all the student information which matches at least one interest of a tutor?

Comment: I think any of the schemas will not be executed. They are not written in a proper way. Could you write your schemas again?

Comment: @Radan I updated the post and hope it is a bit clearer...

Comment: Thank you, its much clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a sql query, i am still thinking of ways to simplify this,

```
SELECT name 
from student 
where 
student.interest1 in ((select interest1 from teacher) UNION (select interest2 from teacher))
or student.interest2 in ((select interest1 from teacher) UNION (select interest2 from teacher));
```

this should work, this query works by checking if interest1 or interest2 of student matches any one interest of the teacher.  Just run this inside cursor it should return you a set of names.

Comment: thank you so much!! it works! I haven't heard about UNION yet. but it works pretty well. thank you!!